# "xmlns:xmlns" is getting added in xml output file using XSLT and exclude-result-prefixes="sii" is not excluding the namespace from elements

Tags: xslt, namespaces

My requirement is to convert below xml file :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <JEES_SSI>
  <P_VAT_ID>10122</P_VAT_ID>
  <LIST_G_LE_DETAILS>
   <G_LE_DETAILS>
    <ENTITYNAME>LE NAME</ENTITYNAME>
    <TAXPAYEID>A0000000A</TAXPAYEID>
   </G_LE_DETAILS>
  </LIST_G_LE_DETAILS>
 </JEES_SSI>
```

To new xml file :(**The required output:**)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas 
   xmlns:siiLR="https:/www.firstschema/SLR.xsd"
   xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.firstschema/ SLR.xsd">
   <sii:Cabecera>
      <sii:Titular>
        <sii:NombreRazon>LE NAME</sii:NombreRazon>
        <sii:NIF>A0000000A</sii:NIF>
     </sii:Titular>
  </sii:Cabecera>
 </siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas>
```

And i am using below XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:siiLR="https:/www.firstschema/SLR.xsd"
     xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd"
     exclude-result-prefixes="sii">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

     <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:element name="siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas">
         <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:siiLR"> <xsl:value-of select= "'https:/www.firstschema/SLR.xsd'" /></xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:sii"> <xsl:value-of select= "'https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd'"/></xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation"> <xsl:value-of select= "'https://www.secondschema/ sinfo.xsd'" /> </xsl:attribute>


    <xsl:element name="sii:Cabecera">

                <xsl:element name="sii:Titular"> 
                    <xsl:element name="sii:NombreRazon"> <xsl:value-of select= "JEES_SSI/LIST_G_LE_DETAILS/G_LE_DETAILS/ENTITYNAME" /> </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="sii:NIF"> <xsl:value-of select= "JEES_SSI/LIST_G_LE_DETAILS/G_LE_DETAILS/TAXPAYERID" /> </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>     
</xsl:element>
```

Output i got:

Output is having additional string for 
xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" which is causing error:
XML Parsing Error: reserved prefix (xmlns) must not be declared or undeclared
and namespace is getting added for first element of sii namespace.

```
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
        <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas xmlns:siiLR="https:/www.firstschema/SLR.xsd" 
          xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" 
          xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.firstschema/ SLR.xsd">
           <sii:Cabecera xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd">
              <sii:Titular>
                 <sii:NombreRazon>LE NAME</sii:NombreRazon>
                 <sii:NIF>A0000000A</sii:NIF>
              </sii:Titular>
           </sii:Cabecera>
        </siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas>
```

Please help to correct the xsl file to get desired xml output file.
There are two different namespace prefix(siiLr and sii) used for elements in xml file.
exclude-result-prefixes="sii" is not excluding the namespace URI from sii:Cabecera

**Modiifed XLS (implementaing suggestion @Stefan Hegny suggestion:**
Issue:xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" is no longer appearing if
 i use below XSL.(Removing xmlns:siiLR and xmlns:sii attributes from root element)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:siiLR="https:/www.firstschema/SLR.xsd"
 xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd"
 >

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:element name="siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas">
  <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation"> <xsl:value-of select= "'https://www.secondschema/ sinfo.xsd'" /> </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="sii:Cabecera">
            <xsl:element name="sii:Titular"> 
                <xsl:element name="sii:NombreRazon"> <xsl:value-of select= "JEES_SSI/LIST_G_LE_DETAILS/G_LE_DETAILS/ENTITYNAME" /> </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="sii:NIF"> <xsl:value-of select= "JEES_SSI/LIST_G_LE_DETAILS/G_LE_DETAILS/TAXPAYERID" /> </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>     
</xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**New output using above XLS:**

```
        <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas     xmlns:siiLR="https:/www.firstschema/SLR.xsd" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.firstschema/ SLR.xsd">
       <sii:Cabecera xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd">
          <sii:Titular>
             <sii:NombreRazon>LE NAME</sii:NombreRazon>
             <sii:NIF>A0000000A</sii:NIF>
          </sii:Titular>
       </sii:Cabecera>
    </siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas>
```

Namespace sii link is appearing in element"Cabecera". It should appear in the root element SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas

[Output with multiple sii element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmjkC.png)

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:attribute name="xmlns:sii">` is adding the xmlns namespace, do you really intend this??

**Edit:** This is not necessary as all the namespace prefixes declared at the top are inherited everywhere. Omit all those attributes `xmlns:sii`, `xmlns:siiLR` etc.

The sii Namespace is used by your created elements like `<xsl:element name="sii:Cabecera">`, and that's why it appears. If you do not want it create the elements without namespace like

`<xsl:element name="Cabecera">`

and do not copy any sii: namespace-prefixed elements into your output.

**Edit 2** for the required output you show

Why would you want to exclude the sii namespace? It is used in your output and so must be in there...

I think the schema location should contain the namespace URL plus the Schema URL, no idea if you should collapse that into one if identical.

I've also simplified several of your xsl:elements that can be written simply as elements.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:siiLR="https:/www.firstschema/SLR.xsd"
     xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

     <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:element name="siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas">
     <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation"><xsl:text>https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>


    <sii:Cabecera>
                <sii:Titular> 
                    <sii:NombreRazon> <xsl:value-of select= "JEES_SSI/LIST_G_LE_DETAILS/G_LE_DETAILS/ENTITYNAME" /> </sii:NombreRazon>
                    <sii:NIF> <xsl:value-of select= "JEES_SSI/LIST_G_LE_DETAILS/G_LE_DETAILS/TAXPAYERID" /> </sii:NIF>
                </sii:Titular>
              </sii:Cabecera>     
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: The Final XML file needs to be validated using XSD. And, 2nd schema sinfo.xsd is being referred in first one SLR.xsd. So without prefix (sii) xml filw won't be validated.

Comment: so the sii namespace prefix is not a problem, but why `name="xmlns:sii"`? Ah, I see, you are trying to implement the schema referencing by hand... well, the sii  and siiLR namespace prefix is inherited from the declaration at the top, no need to specify that again under `<xsl:element name="siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas">`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. If i remove the attribute used for sii and siiLR from root element SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas,output doesn't have information for sii namespace. Only good thing happened that now  xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" is not appearing in  the output.but still has namespace for sii in child element <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas xmlns:siiLR="https:/www.firstschema/SLR.xsd" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.firstschema/ SLR.xsd">
           <sii:Cabecera xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd">

Comment: I suggest you post exactly what the output should look like (plz edit the question). In the comments all this does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: I updated the question with new xsl and corresponding output.Marked the required output too.

Comment: I used your XSL template . In output still namespace URI is appearing in element having prefix sii   .<sii:Cabecera xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd">

Comment: can you describe what happened and in what way it did not meet your requirements?

Comment: My requirement is to have xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd" in root element siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas. While in output this is appearing in each element associated with ssi. e.g <sii:Cabecera xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd"> .  i want it as <sii:Cabecera >.  For asking question i simplified the xml file and added only one element related to sii.  I have multiple elements for sii and each element is having xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd" in output.

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot of output having multiple sii elements.https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmjkC.png

Comment: Technically from xml view this does not make a difference where the sii namespace is defined.  Maybe you try adding `xmlns:sii="https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd"` to `<xsl:element name="siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas">` in xsl?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use siiLR:SuministroLRPagosRecibidas as a xsl:element???
Instead of using :

```
 <xsl:element name="siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas">

 <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation"><xsl:text>https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd https://www.secondschema/sinfo.xsd</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
```

....

Try the following :

xsi:schemaLocation= "https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd SuministroLR.xsd" >

I think this should resolve the issue. Let me know.